# jasper reports barcode using style-Barcode

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to use barcode in *JasperReports* for which I am using the *barcode4j* jar.
The jars that i am using are:

- barcode4j-2.0.jar
- commons-beanutils.jar
- commons-codec-1.6.jar
- commons-collections.jar
- commons-digester-2.0.jar
- commons-lang-2.0.jar
- commons-logging.jar
- commons-net-1.2.2.jar
- commons-validator.jar
- db2jcc.jar
- db2jcc_license_cu.jar
- itext-2.1.7.jar
- jasperreports-4.5.0.jar
- log4j-1.2.8.jar
- poi-3.8-20120326.jar

The *jrxml* file content where I am using barcode is as given below:

```xml
<title>    
    <band height="125">    
        <frame>    
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="40" />    
            <componentElement>    
                <reportElement style="Barcode" x="5" y="5" width="400" height="30"/>    
                <c:Code39 xmlns:c="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components"    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components    http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">    
                    <c:codeExpression>$F{OPA_ACK_NO_PK}</c:codeExpression>    
                </c:Code39>    
            </componentElement>    
        </frame>    
    </band>    
</title>
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not resolve style(s): Barcode4j
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillObjectFactory.checkUnresolvedReferences(JRFillObjectFactory.java:1577)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillObjectFactory.setStyles(JRFillObjectFactory.java:1504)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.loadStyles(JRBaseFiller.java:912)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:804)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:746)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:58)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:417)
at Report.Test.main(Test.java:162)
```

Please guide me as to what am I doing wrong?

After removing the comment for Barcode style tag, i got rid of that error and got another exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/batik/bridge/UserAgent
    at net.sf.jasperreports.components.barcode4j.BarcodeSVGImageProducer.createImage(BarcodeSVGImageProducer.java:69)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.components.barcode4j.BarcodeFillComponent.setBarcodeImage(BarcodeFillComponent.java:149)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.components.barcode4j.BarcodeFillComponent.fill(BarcodeFillComponent.java:113)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillComponentElement.fill(JRFillComponentElement.java:148)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.fillElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:570)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillFrame.fill(JRFillFrame.java:276)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.fillElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:570)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:406)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:352)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillTitle(JRVerticalFiller.java:323)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:257)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:128)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:836)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:746)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:58)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:417)
    at Report.Test.main(Test.java:169)
```

I added the required batik, crimson, xerces and xercesImpl jars. But I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.batik.bridge.ViewBox.getPreserveAspectRatioTransform([FSZFF)Ljava/awt/geom/AffineTransform; from class net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.BatikRenderer
    at net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.BatikRenderer.render(BatikRenderer.java:123)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportImage(JRPdfExporter.java:1405)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportElements(JRPdfExporter.java:757)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportFrame(JRPdfExporter.java:2554)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportElements(JRPdfExporter.java:765)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportPage(JRPdfExporter.java:721)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:635)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:383)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(JasperExportManager.java:122)
    at Report.Test.main(Test.java:172)
```

Comment: Did you check the *Barcode4j* style declaration in your report? You can try to remove style reference for *Barcode* component

Comment: Thank you Alex from ur prompt help.. I had actually commented the barcode style in my jrxml..

Comment: Alex, i couldnt answer to this question right now.. so i have edited the question.. please have a look at the same..

Comment: Can it be due to some deprecated method being called??

Comment: You should compare libraries versions with ones from *JR*'s pom.xml

Comment: I just checked for the deprecated methods..  public static AffineTransform getPreserveAspectRatioTransform(Element, float, float) is Deprecated.. however the BatikRenderer is actually calling public static AffineTransform getPreserveAspectRatioTransform(float[], short, boolean, float, float) method..

Comment: May be it happened, because you are using the libraries of wrong versions

Comment: Yes.. You are absolutely correct. Its sorted. I had been using Batik 1.5 jars. I replaced it with Batik 1.7 and it is all good. Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 7):

You should add library batik-bridge:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>batik</groupId>
    <artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId>
    <version>1.6-1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Gives me an issue: GRAVE: null
org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing

Comment: library gives you an issue? Are you using Geotk 4.x SNAPSHOT?

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday i had exactly the same problem, i succeded to resolve it by using:

```
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement x="311" y="166" width="180" height="10"/>
            <jr:barbecue xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" type="Code39 (Extended)" drawText="false" checksumRequired="false">
                <jr:codeExpression><![CDATA[$P{barcode}]]></jr:codeExpression>
            </jr:barbecue>
        </componentElement>
```

Comment: Thank you Shessuky. I resolved that by updating the Batik jars with 1.7 version.

Comment: In this case you just using another lib

Answer (score 1):

For me adding `batik-bridge` with below dependency to project `pom.xml` worked:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```